# SD Initialization Failing

Tags: arduino-mega, shields, sd-card

I am using a SEEED SD Card Shield. Everytime I attempt to write the card, I get

When Using File> Examples> SD > CardInfo:

```
initialization failed. Things to check:
* is a card is inserted?
* Is your wiring correct?
* did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?
```

Or when using File>Examples> SD> Files:

```
Initializing SD card...initialization failed!
```

I even tried SdFat (IDE couldn't find anything), the "SD Library" by Adafruit (No change), and other things.

I'm using a Funduino MEGA 2560. Could that be the problem?!

Comment: Are you using an Ethernet shield as well? I have had problems with chip select line definitions on a Freetronics EtherMega2560 which is basically a standard 2560 with an inbuilt Ethernet shield.

Answer (score 2):

I also use a Seeed Studio SD Shield, and used to have the same problem. To rectify this I have to insert the SD card into my PC and Format it. This almost always helped. If you have a card that has too large of storage, the Arduino will take too much time to check the full memory for information stored on it (initialize). Some SD card readers require a card of 2 gigabytes or less to work. Check the Data Sheet for this limit (if there is one). That should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I spent ages failing to get my SD card working. Then installed an earlier version (1.0.8) of the SD library which fixed the issue for me.